# JavaScript autocomplete on imported modules in GitHub's Atom

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, atom-editor

I'm trying to get familiar with GitHub's Atom and working with JavaScript on a large-scale project. I've been working with tutorials, and the biggest complaint I'm having with Atom is that I can't find a way to get the out of the box autocomplete to work consistently.

For example, I'm following a relatively simple Node.js tutorial, using ES6 syntax, and I have the following code in a `core.js` file:

```
export function logMe(message) {
  console.log('message: ' + message);
}
```

In `main.js` file, I have the following:

```
import {logMe} from '../src/core'

logMe('Hello, world!');
```

However, when typing in `main.js`, I get no autocomplete suggestions for `logMe` or anything in my `core.js` file. I feel like there should be either some existing functionality in [`autocomplete-plus`](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus), or another plugin, that allows autocomplete to work across `import` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [atom-ternjs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs) it is Atom integration with the excellent [TernJS](http://ternjs.net/). You will need to spend a bit of time generating your `.tern-project` file by going to the `Packages` menu → `Atom Ternjs` → `Configure Project`, but once you have it setup it works very well.

If you don't want to go down the TernJS route, then there is a setting for the `autocomplete-plus` package called `Include Completions from All Buffers`:

[image: Include Completions from All Buffers]

In my experience it can create a lot of noise and is dependent upon a the other files being open which doesn't scale well.

Comment: I saw that mentioned, but didn't go through the setup yet. I guess I'm just surprised that such a seemingly common method for organizing javascript code renders Atom's built-in autocomplete less-than-useful....

Comment: tern-js does seem to work for my use case in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it works for you.  Your comment reminded me that there is a `Include Completions from All Buffers` setting for `autocomplete-plus`, I've updated my answer to include the reference to it.  Thanks for the accept and the upvote.